# Watir/Selenium2 Nothing happens after clicking on an element inside iframe in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, ruby, watir-webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing autotests with Watir-WebDriver and Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu for the web. I have some iframe with several elements. I need to click on the items and check what happens. The `<iframe>` looks like:

```
<iframe id="iframe" align="top" some_attribute="some_attribute">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Some title </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <button id="id_button" type="button" class="some_class"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

When I click on the button, it should create the menu. But when I click on the button with watir-webdriver, nothing happens, as if he did not pressed. Watir don't print any exceptions, but do not press the button.

This problem persists only for Internet Explorer. For Firefox and Chrome, there is no problem. My code looks like:

```
browser = Watir :: Browser.new (: remote,: url => "http://some_ip:4444/wd/hub",: desired_capabilities =>: internet_explorer)
browser.goto ("http://some_http.com")
browser.iframe.button (: id, "id_button"). click
```

If I write

```
browser.iframe.button(: id, "id_button").attribute_value("class")
```

It's returning `"some_class"`. This indicates that the item is recognized, but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a javascript command?

Eg:

```
browser.iframe.button(:id, "id_button").fire_event("onclick")
```

If that doesn't work, try debugging using IRB.

PS: I would write it as follows:

```
browser.iframe(:id, /iframe/).button(:id, /button/).fire_event("onclick")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
browser.iframe(:id, "iframe").button (: id, "id_button").click
```

if you need more information, check this link

http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames